# my second "levelup" button is not working also update function is not getting called from fight and levelup functions

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAddMonster" type="button" onclick="addMonster()">Buy Monster</button>

    <button id="btnLevelUpMonster" type="button" onclick="levelUpMonster()">Levelup Monster</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="fight()">Fight</button>
    <div id="logs">

    </div>
    <div id="variables">

    </div>
    <div id="monstersInfo">

        monster

    </div>

    <script src="GameScript.js">  </script>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code

```
var Monster = [{
    "HitPoint" : 100,
    "Damage" : 5,
    "level" : 1
},
]
var log = ["Welcome to DungeonCircus",""]
var gold = 500;
var monsterLevel = 1;
var exp = 0;

function addMonster(){
    if (gold>=Monster.length*80){
        gold-=Monster.length*80
        var temp={};
        temp.level=monsterLevel;
        temp.Damage = 5*temp.level+Math.floor((Math.random()-Math.random())*0.8*temp.level);
        temp.HitPoint = 100*temp.level+Math.floor(10*(Math.random()-Math.random())*temp.level);
        Monster.push(temp);
        monstersInfoUpdate();
        document.getElementById("btnAddMonster").innerHTML="Add Monster ("+(Monster.length*80).toString()+")";
    }
    else{
        alert("Low on gold")
    }
}


function levelUpMonster(){
    if(exp>=monsterLevel * 10){
        exp-=monsterLevel * 10;
        monsterlevel += 1;
        document.getElementById("btnLevelUpMonster").innerHTML="LevelUp Monster ("+(monsterLevel*10).toString()+")";
        variablesUpdate();
    } else{
        alert("Low on exp")
    }

}

function fight(){
    var hpPoints=0;
    var damagePoints=0;
    var i;
    var l=Monster.length;
    for(i=0;i<Monster.length;i++){
        hpPoints+=Monster[i].HitPoint;
        damagePoints+=Monster[i].Damage;
    }
    gold+=damagePoints*80;
    exp += hpPoints;
    while(Monster.length){
        Monster.pop();
    }
    monstersInfoUpdate();
}


function monstersInfoUpdate(){
    var str="";
    var i=Monster.length;
    str+="<b><br>Monster : "+(i).toString()+"</b>";
    for (var i=0;i<Monster.length;i++){


        str+="<br> Level : "+Monster[i].level + "     HitPoints : " + Monster[i].HitPoint + "      Damage : " + Monster[i].Damage;
        document.getElementById("monstersInfo").innerHTML=str;

    }
    variablesUpdate();
}

function variablesUpdate(){
    var str="Gold : "+gold;
    str+=" Monster Level : "+monsterLevel;
    str+=" Exp : "+ exp;
    document.getElementById("variables").innerHTML=str;
    document.getElementById("btnAddMonster").innerHTML="Add Monster ("+(Monster.length*80).toString()+")";
    document.getElementById("btnLevelUpMonster").innerHTML="LevelUp Monster ("+(monsterLevel*10).toString()+")";
}

monstersInfoUpdate();
document.getElementById("btnAddMonster").innerHTML="Add Monster ("+(Monster.length*80).toString()+")";
document.getElementById("btnLevelUpMonster").innerHTML="LevelUp Monster ("+(monsterLevel*10).toString()+")";


document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML=log;
```

the "levelup monster" is not working as it should and the updatevariable function is not being called in levelup monster and updatemonsterInfo is not getting called in fight function. any help is appreciated. the buttons are working fine with alert message but it is not working when the given functions are called.

Added this to the code and the heroInfoUpdate is not getting called same problem as before

```
function heroesInfoUpdate(){
    var str="";
    var i=Heroes.length;
    str+="<b><br>Heroes : "+(i).toString()+"</b>";
    for (i=0;i<Heroes.length;i++){


        str+="<br> Level : "+Heroes[i].level + "     HitPoints : " + Heroes[i].HitPoint + "      Damage : " + Heroes[i].Damage;
        document.getElementById("heroesInfo").innerHTML=str;

    }
    variablesUpdate();
}



function addHero(){
    if (gold>=Heroes.length*80){
        gold-=Heroes.length*80
        var temp={};
        temp.level=heroesLevel;
        temp.Damage = 10*temp.level+Math.floor((Math.random()-Math.random())*0.8*temp.level);
        temp.HitPoint = 80*temp.level+Math.floor(10*(Math.random()-Math.random())*temp.level);
        Heroes.push(temp);
        heroesInfoUpdate();
    }
    else{
        alert("Low on gold")
    }
}


function levelUpHeroes(){
    if(exp>=HeroesLevel * 100){
        exp-=HeroesLevel * 100;
        heroLevel += 1;
        variablesUpdate();
    } else{
        alert("Low on exp")
    }

}
```

the new html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAddMonster" type="button" onclick="addMonster();">Buy Monster</button>

    <button id="btnLevelUpMonster" type="button" onclick="levelUpMonster();">Levelup Monster</button>

    <button id="btnAddHero" type="button" onclick="addHero();">Buy Hero</button>

    <button id="btnLevelUpHero" type="button" onclick="levelUpHero();">Levelup Hero</button>


    <button type="button" onclick="fight()">Fight</button>
    <div id="logs">

    </div>
    <div id="variables">

    </div>
    <div id="heroesInfo">

        HeroInfo

    </div>

    <div id="monstersInfo">

        monsterInfo

    </div>

    <script src="GameScript.js">  </script>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function variablesUpdate(){
    var str="Gold : "+gold;
    str+=" Monster Level : "+monsterLevel;
    str+=" Exp : "+ exp;
    document.getElementById("variables").innerHTML=str;
    document.getElementById("btnAddMonster").innerHTML="Add Monster ("+(Monster.length*80).toString()+")";//the * operator needs to be seperated with a whitespace everywhere
    document.getElementById("btnLevelUpMonster").innerHTML="LevelUp Monster ("+(monsterLevel*10).toString()+")";
}
```

the * operator needs to be seperated with a whitespace everywhere most probably. 
And there are some typos here and there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the LevelupMonster Function.

```
function levelUpMonster(){
    if(exp>=monsterLevel * 10){
        exp-=monsterLevel * 10;
        monsterlevel += 1; //==============> here should come monsterLevel "L" caps
        document.getElementById("btnLevelUpMonster").innerHTML="LevelUp Monster ("+(monsterLevel*10).toString()+")";
        variablesUpdate();
    } else{
        alert("Low on exp")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx and about that monsterinfoupdate function not getting called from fight function and levelup function

Comment: kindly let me know the flow of the game.What does fight function do what it updates etc

Comment: Fight function generates gold and exp and all the monster get killed, that is they are popped off array. The fight function is working but the call made to updatemonsterinfo is not working. Similarly call to variablesupdate is not working in levelupMonster function

Comment: everything seems to be working fine. the fight function pops out all the array so thats why the updatenonstinfo is not working. it doesnt go into the loop because the array is empty.Varialbe update seems to updating everything as well

Comment: i think there is some other error as after making more additions to the code found similar error as now the hero info is not updating.